# Not able to increase code coverage in Angular Unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I am trying to learn how to make unit testing for Angular with Karma and Jasmine.

My problem is that I make it with spyOn() and expect.toHaveBeenCalled() and even though Karma says that passed the tests, the Code Coverage is not updated.

I am new to angular unit testing and I dont know how to test methods properly so as to get code coverage.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: You only test one of both methods though...

Comment: BTW, whats the purpose of injecting a service, create a new one and still not use any of those instances as your methods are static?! You should either extract those methods from the class and export them as individual functions, or make then instance-methods.

Comment: I know im just testing one. The problem is that the one I am testing isnt getting marked as Tested, and the one I am not testing is getting marked as tested.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to unit testing and maybe thats why I made non-sense injections.

Comment: `spyOn(EnvironmentService, 'isProduction');` overwrites the service method and then `EnvironmentService.isProduction();` is calling a spy instead of your method. Thus your method isn't called. valid test would be removing spy and something like `expect(EnvironmentService.isProduction()).toBe(false)`

Comment: Thats it. Thanks @Andrei I know it was a shitty question but Im so noob with this. I can mark your comment as answer if you make it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spyOn(EnvironmentService, 'isProduction');` overwrites the service method and then `EnvironmentService.isProduction();` is calling a spy instead of your method. Thus your method isn't called. valid test would be removing spy and will looke in some way like `expect(EnvironmentService.isProduction()).toBe(false)`

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need not just create a spy but also execute it to increase coverage. A spy replaces the spied function with a stub. If you want this spy function to be called normally, you need to add **.and.callThrough()** to your spy.

```
spyOn(EnvironmentService, 'isProduction').and.callThrough()
```

You can also read more here: [about spy and callThrough](https://hatoum.com/blog/2016/11/12/jasmine-unit-testing-dont-forget-to-callthrough)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for ur help too